# How to concatenate different lines in a data frame columns based on another column value?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame in R looking like this

```
> mydata=data.frame(id=c(rep("gene1",3),rep("gene2",4),rep("gene3",1),rep("gene4",2)),description=c(rep("protein1",3),rep("protein2",4),rep("protein3",1),rep("protein4",2)),type=c(rep("coding",10)),name=c("nucleus","binding","ribosome","transcription factor","regulation of transcription","DNA","sequence-specific binding","hydrolase","transporter","ion transport"),definition=paste(rep("blabla",10),1:10))
> mydata
  id     description   type                        name definition
1  gene1    protein1 coding                     nucleus   blabla 1
2  gene1    protein1 coding                     binding   blabla 2
3  gene1    protein1 coding                    ribosome   blabla 3
4  gene2    protein2 coding        transcription factor   blabla 4
5  gene2    protein2 coding regulation of transcription   blabla 5
6  gene2    protein2 coding                         DNA   blabla 6
7  gene2    protein2 coding   sequence-specific binding   blabla 7
8  gene3    protein3 coding                   hydrolase   blabla 8
9  gene4    protein4 coding                 transporter   blabla 9
10 gene4    protein4 coding               ion transport   blabla 10
```

I need to transform it like this

```
> mydata2=data.frame(id=c("gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4"),description=c("protein1","protein2","protein3","protein4"),type=c(rep("coding",4)),name=c("nucleus,binding,ribosome","transcription factor,regulation of transcription,DNA","sequence-specific binding","hydrolase,transporter,ion transport"),definition=paste(rep("blabla",4),c(3,7,8,10)))
> mydata2
    id description   type                                                 name   definition
1 gene1    protein1 coding                             nucleus,binding,ribosome   blabla 3
2 gene2    protein2 coding transcription factor,regulation of transcription,DNA   blabla 7
3 gene3    protein3 coding                            sequence-specific binding   blabla 8
4 gene4    protein4 coding                  hydrolase,transporter,ion transport   blabla 10
```

I have tried several functions

```
dcast
reshape2
spread
```

But I don't get what I need. For reshape2 for example, it creates a new column for each different entry in $name.

Can someone help? Thanks a lot

PS: first post, I hope the editing is ok, forgive me otherwise

Comment: Could you check your expected output matches your input? Especially the 'definition'-column. Do you always use the last one for a certain id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you? It splits your data by id, description and types. For each subset, it pastes names together and selects the last definition.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
res <- mydata[,list(name=paste(name,collapse=", "),
                    definition=definition[.N]),
by=list(id, description,type)]
res

 id description   type                                                                              name definition
1: gene1    protein1 coding                                                        nucleus, binding, ribosome   blabla 3
2: gene2    protein2 coding transcription factor, regulation of transcription, DNA, sequence-specific binding   blabla 7
3: gene3    protein3 coding                                                                         hydrolase   blabla 8
4: gene4    protein4 coding                                                        transporter, ion transport  blabla 10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Heroka, it works perfectly. Yes I always use the last definition for an id because it's always the most detailed one in this specific dataset. May I also ask you what definition=definition[.N] means/how to use this kind of writing (.N)?

Comment: Of course. .N is a data.table-function/method to get the number of rows in a group. So with your data grouped by id, description and type, .N represents the number of rows for each combination and thus the position of the last definition. Note that this hangs on the order of your dataset.

Comment: Ok. So if I wanted to keep the definition before last, I could just write (.N-1)? Thanks

Comment: That wouldn't work if there was only one observation